# Merging corresponding elements of two lists to a new list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists as shown below,car_xy and car_id. I have wrote a sample code to merge the corresponding elements of both lists, but am not getting the desired output.

```
car_xy =[(650,700),(568,231),(789,123),(968,369)]
car_id =[284,12,466,89]
#required_details merges the two lists
required_details = list(set(car_xy+car_id))
#now if i do print required_details the ouput will be a list like;
required_details = [284,12,(650,700),89,(568,231),466,(968,369),(789,123)] 
#the required details adds the information in list randomly. What if i want  the first elements of both the list together, like
required_details = [[284,(650,700)],[12,(568,231),[466,(789,123)],[89,(968,369)]]
```

Any suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you need `[list(pair) for pair in zip(car_id, car_xy)]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the arrays are same length, you loop through them and combine them like this:

```
required_details = []
for i in range(len(car_xy)):
    required_details.append([car_id[i], car_xy[i]])
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'` (py2.7)

Comment: @AyushShanker ah yeah it's actually .append() in python fixed the answer

Comment: @Quartal its giving a Type error:can only concatenate tuple (not '''int') to tuple

Answer (score 0):

you are searching for the `zip` function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

```
car_xy =[(650,700),(568,231),(789,123),(968,369)]
car_id =[284,12,466,89]
required_details = zip(car_id,car_xy)
```

Edit:
adding the following makes it a list, in case there is a need for mutation.

```
req_details_list = [list(pair) for pair in required_details]
```

Comment: the corresponding elements are not listed together in this.

Comment: added list creation in case this is really needed